# if no row found in table add button should be display else edit using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

in a row record found means edit button should be display or add button and no row found in a table it should be display add button,i am getting a problem while no row in table displaying edit but i want display add button please refer my below code.

**Controller**

```
$result = $this->Profile_model->buyer_details();
        $data['c_address'] = $result->address;
        $data['c_pincode'] = $result->pincode;
        $data['c_district'] = $result->district;
        $data['c_city'] = $result->city;
        $data['c_state'] = $result->state;
        $data['c_country'] = $result->country;

        $this->load->view('buyerdetails', $data);
```

**Model code**

```
public function buyer_details() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('customer_otherdetails');
        $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $rows = $query->result(); //so you only have to call result once
        // $rows = $query->result_array();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                //add all data to session
                $newdataa = array(
                    'address' => $row->address,
                    'pincode' => $row->pincode,
                    'city' => $row->city,
                    'district' => $row->district,
                    'state' => $row->state,
                    'country' => $row->country,
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata('buyer', $newdataa);
            //put the return outside the if
            //return $query->result();
        }
        // return $rows; //this will be an empty array if no data found
        return $query->row();
    }
```

**view page**

```
<a onclick="hideHasSub()" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseone">
                                            <?php
                                            if (empty($c_country) == $this->session->userdata('buyer')) {
                                                ?>
                                                <span class="profile-edit">Add</span>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                                <span class="profile-edit">Edit</span>
<?php } ?>
                                        </a>
```

Comment: what error show ??

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want to achieve at a particular point, but if you use `session` wouldn't you, in case your query returns `0`, just set a session value `0/1` you can later re-use ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->id);
```

here change

```
 $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->userdata('id');
```

now your model ::

```
public function buyer_details() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('customer_otherdetails');
        $this->db->where('customerid_fk', $this->session->userdata('id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $rows = $query->result(); //so you only have to call result once
        // $rows = $query->result_array();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                //add all data to session
                $newdataa = array(
                    'address' => $row->address,
                    'pincode' => $row->pincode,
                    'city' => $row->city,
                    'district' => $row->district,
                    'state' => $row->state,
                    'country' => $row->country,
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata('buyer', $newdataa);
            //put the return outside the if
            //return $query->result();
        }
        // return $rows; //this will be an empty array if no data found
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in "a" tag

```
<?php
 if (empty($c_country[0]) || empty($c_country)){?>
<span class="profile-edit">Add</span>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="profile-edit">Edit</span>
<?php } ?>
```